# Independent sessions for each tabs C# WebApi / Angular2+

Tags: c#, angular, session, asp.net-web-api2

We are building aWeb app that allows users to open different projects they created using this app. The front-end is an Angular 4 app with a REST Architecture and the backend a C# Asp.net Web Api.

Our problem is that we store all our backend datas in a Session (because it's a huge object with mathematical datas and formulas in it), and when we open multiple projects in different tabs, the session become in common between each tabs so it causes interferences.

We are trying to find a way to attach each instance of the app (each project) with an unique session in the server. We look for using GUID stored in `window.name` for each tab, then sent to the server which has `HttpContext.Current.Session["GUIDSessionID"];` that stores our object but we did not find the way to make it work, as we are beginners in c# development.

Here are the links we look for to find a solution (without success) :

- http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/02/get-a-unique-session-in-each-browser-tab/
- https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/364203/Stop-Sharing-Session-State-between-Multiple-Tabs-o

Thanks in advance.
Nikolas

Answer (score 0):

Generate a unique session id a hash or something.
In Angular to store it can put locale localStorage.setItem('GUIDSessionID', 'YourSessionID');.

If you want to get it even after a refresh localStorage.getItem('GUIDSessionID');

If you login with a new generate new SessionID remove old localStorage.removeItem('GUIDSessionID') and set new.

Comment: Yes but how could we pass this unique id to the webapi and create a specific session for this GUID ? That's our major issue.

Comment: Send it with the login at first time.
Make a new backend call and send the sessionID, then check if the current sessionID = sessionID of the login.
You can check with a timer like every 30 seconds. and if 15 minutes have past with no reply can automatic logout.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is by -

- reading the project ID from URL/querystring and put that in some hidden field on the page.
- Create all the session variables with key starting that project ID.

For example, if your project ID is '654654481CEG', your session assignment will be something like this:

```
Session[string.Format("{0}-projectName", "654654481CEG")] = "WhateverYourValueIs";
```

While reading the value back from session, you will do the same -

```
string strprojectName = Session[string.Format("{0}-projectName", "654654481CEG")].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a coworker and we used sort of sub-sessions:

```
//We changed this
HttpContext.Current.Session["x"] = x;
HttpContext.Current.Session["y"] = y;
//To this
HttpContext.Current.Session["guid"] = new SessionContent{x = x, y = y };
```

and we did as follow :
BackEnd

```
public static class SessionUtils
{
    public class SessionContent
    {
        public XClass xProperty{ get; set; }
        public YClass yProperty{ get; set; }
    }

    public static string GetSessionGUID(IHttpRouteData route)
    {
        return route.Values["guid"].ToString();
    }

    public static XClass GetSessionXProperty(HttpContextBase httpContextBase, IHttpRouteData route)
    {
        return ((SessionUtils.SessionContent)httpContextBase.Session[GetSessionGUID(route)]).xProperty;
    }

    public static void SetSessionXProperty(HttpContextBase httpContextBase, IHttpRouteData route, XClass xProperty)
    {
        ((SessionUtils.SessionContent)httpContextBase.Session[GetSessionGUID(route)]).xProperty= xProperty;
    }

    public static YClass GetSessionYProperty(HttpContextBase httpContextBase, IHttpRouteData route)
    {
        return ((SessionUtils.SessionContent)httpContextBase.Session[GetSessionGUID(route)]).yProperty;
    }

    public static void SetSessionYProperty(HttpContextBase httpContextBase, IHttpRouteData route, YClass yProperty)
    {
        ((SessionUtils.SessionContent)httpContextBase.Session[GetSessionGUID(route)]).yProperty= yProperty;
    }
}
```

Here is an controller for example:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    private HttpContextBase _httpContext;

    public TestController ()
    {
         _httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
    }
    public AuditTrailController(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        _httpContext = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Send}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Send()
    {
        XClass x = SessionUtils.GetSessionXProperty(_httpContext, Request.GetRouteData());
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return response;
    }
}
```

And in Angular front we just generate a GUID, send it to the back end while initiating the project and add it to each request we make.

```
window.name = UUID.UUID();
```

Then in services :

```
return this.http.get(environment.baseUrl + '/' + window.name + '/myController/')
      .map(res => res.json());
```